# Updated_at row doesn't update when i update pivot column

Tags: adonis.js

I have a small issue when i want to update my pivot table.
I have 3 tables : products, commands and command_products. When i want to update the products throught the command_products

```
public async updateProduct({
request,
params,
response,
}: HttpContextContract) {
const command = await Command.find(params.id);
const allProducts = request.body().products;

if (command) {
  const productData = {};
  for (const product of allProducts) {
    productData[product.product_id] = {
      quantity: product.quantity,
    };
  }
  // L'option false rajoute des produits et ne supprime pas les rows déjà existants.
  // await command.related("products").sync(productData, false);
  await command.related("products").sync(productData);
  await command.load("products");
  await command.load("user")
  
  // command.updated_at = Date.now()
  if (await command.save()) {
    return response.json({
      message: "command succefully updated",
      command_updated: command,
    });
  }
  return; // 422
}
return; // 401
}
```

I use the sync() méthod, all work fine but the updated_at row i receive from the response doesn't change.

Here my models command and product :

```
export default class Command extends BaseModel {
@column({ isPrimary: true })
public id: number

@column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true })
public created_at: DateTime

@column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true, autoUpdate: true })
public updated_at: DateTime

@column()
public user_id: number 

@belongsTo(() => User, { foreignKey: "user_id"})
public user: BelongsTo<typeof User>

@manyToMany(() => Product, {
pivotTable: 'command_products',
pivotColumns: ['quantity'],
pivotTimestamps: true

})
public products: ManyToMany<typeof Product> 
}



export default class Product extends BaseModel {
@column({ isPrimary: true })
public id: number
@column()
public title: string;

@column()
public description: string;

@column()
public price: number;

@column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true })
public created_at: DateTime
@column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true, autoUpdate: true })
public updated_at: DateTime

@manyToMany(() => Command, {
pivotTable: 'command_products',
pivotTimestamps: true

})
public commands: ManyToMany<typeof Command>

@computed()
public get quantity() {
const quantity = this.$extras.pivot_quantity
return quantity
}
}
```

I just think the sync() method doesn't update the date but i can't find anything about that.
Thanks !

EDIT : the date is updated in the pivot table but not in the command table. I think this is a normal behavior but may be is there a way to update the date command itself ?